# select n rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
Country | Capital
----------------------
France  |  Paris
Germany | Berlin
USA     | Washington
Russia  | Moscow.
```

I need to select all rows except the first one.The  table is having no primary key.
How should i  do this?

Comment: what constitutes as "first" row without a PK?

Comment: Even *with* a PK there is no "first row" as a PK does not impose any ordering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT country, capitol, rownum as rn
   FROM your_table
   ORDER BY country
) 
WHERE rn > 1
```

If the "first one" is not defined through sorting by country, then you need to apply a different `ORDER BY` in the inner query.

**Edit**

For completeness, the ANSI SQL solution to this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT country, 
          capitol, 
          row_number() over (order by country) as rn
   FROM your_table
) 
WHERE rn > 1
```

That is a portable solution that works on almost all major DBMS

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it with Oracle is the following:

```
SELECT country, capital FROM 
       ( SELECT rownum rn, country, capital
           FROM table
       )
 WHERE rn > 1
```

You cannot put a direct `>N` condition on rownum, because ROWNUMs are assigned when rows are fetched and your condition will never evaluate to TRUE.

Alternative is:

```
SELECT country, capital FROM table
 MINUS
SELECT country, capital FROM table WHERE rownum <= 1
```

Comment: -1 this makes no sense. Why not just fetch all the records and discard one of them at random?

Comment: @Jefrey Kemp: Maybe it makes no sense, but this is what the OP asked for.